# How to identify if your hardware is working properly?

Tags: command-line, wireless, drivers, gui

I'm thinking of moving from Windows to Linux for the past few days, and I've read some question here but I want to know more about certain things especially in drivers. They said that Linux doesn't require drivers, but I've read that one of the answer in a question here that says that some hardware needs to be install like WiFi and graphics card.

I know how to use Linux, and most of the time I use terminal simply because online guides always tell me what commands to run. However, I'm not sure what to do outside of that.

In Windows, I can see all installed hardware through Device Manager. Does such a thing exist for Linux? Is it a command, or is there a graphical package to do this

Comment: The thing about Linux is that some hardware, such as Broadcom wireless cards, require proprietary drivers (or in Linux language - modules ).  In my experience, Realtek cards, work decently enough. So it's really all about the manufacturers  , or rather how well they play with open-source community.

Answer (score 6):

I think your best bet would be `lshw`, `lspci`, `lspcmcia`, and `lsusb`. These are all terminal-based, meaning you have to run them in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

These three commands (and their flags, see `man <command>` for more info) can tell you a lot about your system.

However, <s>most</s> all of these tools are limited to only being able to see what your kernel can see. If the kernel can't see it, it usually means the hardware is poorly installed, dead, or broken. Additionally, these commands do not help you do active troubleshooting on your devices. They are purely informative -- they will not directly help you install drivers, etc.

### `lshw`

---

An all-around report of what hardware you have in your computer. It doesn't detect *everything*, but it's definitely a good step.

See `man lshw` for more information.

**Example Output:**

```
[redacted]               
    description: Notebook
    product: [redacted]
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: [redacted]
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Q sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=1B63B879-2A96-C097-DD6B-10C37B1EECDE
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: [redacted]
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345678901234567
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: [redacted]
          date: 06/16/2014
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 8
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: a
             slot: CPU Internal L1
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: b
             slot: CPU Internal L3
             size: 4MiB
             capacity: 4MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: c
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: M471B5173QH0-YK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 15A0DE9D
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 1
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: M471B5173QH0-YK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 2
             serial: 15A0DE9C
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 3
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:59 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:63 memory:f7a1c000-f7a1ffff
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7a10000-f7a17fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:56 memory:f7a00000-f7a0ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP HECI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:60 memory:f7a24000-f7a2401f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:62 memory:f7a18000-f7a1bfff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7900000-f79fffff ioport:f2100000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 0c
                serial: 10:c3:7b:1e:ec:de
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:58 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7900000-f7900fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 memory:f7800000-f78fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 6b
                serial: 80:86:f2:23:78:69
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-43-generic firmware=25.228.9.0 ip=10.0.2.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:61 memory:f7800000-f7801fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-generic UNCLAIMED
                description: Unassigned class
                product: Illegal Vendor ID
                vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: ff
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list
                configuration: latency=255 maxlatency=255 mingnt=255
                resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:57 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7a22000-f7a227ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7a21000-f7a210ff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Lynx Point-LP Thermal
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7a20000-f7a20fff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST1000LM024 HN-M
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 0002
             serial: S2Y4J9DF302858
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=3ed421d9-4412-4dfe-ab2e-ec026958789b sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 79ce-21ea
                size: 1126MiB
                capacity: 1127MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=EFI
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: 72182df1-59f4-4645-ab5d-c51c8574253d
                size: 509GiB
                capacity: 509GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-12-18 19:09:28 filesystem=ntfs label=Windows modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 2653-69df
                size: 420MiB
                capacity: 449MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-06-01 22:45:26 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
           *-volume:3
                description: Apple Core Storage (File Vault)
                vendor: Mac OS X (journaled)
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 5
                serial: 70a6d4ed-70bc-c40c-0000-000000640000
                size: 199GiB
                capacity: 199GiB
                capabilities: encrypted hfsx journaled bootable osx hfsplus initialized
                configuration: boot=osx checked=2015-01-01 21:58:27 created=2015-01-01 21:58:27 filesystem=hfsplus lastmountedby=HFSJ modified=2015-05-15 11:03:06 name=Mac OS X state=unclean
           *-volume:4
                description: boot partition
                vendor: Mac OS X (journaled)
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 4
                serial: 3081fb24-64d6-7690-0000-000000005000
                size: 619MiB
                capacity: 619MiB
                capabilities: boot journaled bootable macos osx hfsplus initialized
                configuration: checked=2015-01-01 14:03:07 created=2015-01-01 14:03:07 filesystem=hfsplus lastmountedby=HFSJ modified=2015-05-15 11:03:01 name=Recovery HD state=unclean
           *-volume:5
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                version: 3.1
                serial: 4630-ec9c
                size: 894MiB
                capacity: 899MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-12-18 19:09:24 filesystem=ntfs label=Recovery state=clean
           *-volume:6
                description: reserved partition
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                serial: d8318946-2259-48b7-b7c8-91326f7b4537
                capacity: 127MiB
                capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:7
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 8
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,8
                logical name: /dev/sda8
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 2f30acd8-6985-413e-97d0-1317ff84734d
                size: 211GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2015-07-16 11:39:47 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2015-07-18 15:32:54 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2015-07-18 15:32:54 state=mounted
           *-volume:8
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 9
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,9
                logical name: /dev/sda9
                version: 1
                serial: c3ccac50-afff-49ce-97ce-23c42e1716b2
                size: 8191MiB
                capacity: 8191MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RAM UJ8E2 S
             vendor: MATSHITA
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 1.00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

**N.B.** This command should be run as super-user (`sudo lshw`) for most effectiveness.

### `lspci`

---

This command limits its search to the PCI bus and everything connected to it. It's good for more verbose information on what physical devices are in your computer. Also, `lspci -k` will display all devices and their appropriate kernel drivers -- good for seeing what's actively enabled and what's not.

See `man lspci` for more information.

**Sample Output:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP Thermal (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 745M] (rev ff)
```

### `lspcmcia`

---

This command will list all PCMCIA devices installed on your computer. However, most modern computers no longer have PCMCIA ports, so this command will likely return null.

See `man lspcmcia` for more information.

### `lsusb`

---

This command is essentially a `lspci` for USB. It displays the USB buses and everything connected to them. It's best used to find what peripherals are in your computer.

See `man lsusb` for more information.

**Example Output:**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 04f3:010c Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1532:003e Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### Bonus: `lscpu`

---

The above tools aren't always the best at finding processor information. This command is designed specifically for this purpose, and will give you very detailed information.

See `man lscpu` for more information.

**Example Output:**

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2124.281
BogoMIPS:              4789.14
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

### Bonus: `lsdev`

---

This command is a very advanced list of all the devices on your system. It's not installed by default, you need to install `proctools` like so:

```
sudo apt-get install proctools
```

It is best-suited to finding what I/O addresses, DMAs, and IRQs the devices are using.

See `man lsdev` for more information

**Example Output:**

```
Device            DMA   IRQ  I/O Ports
------------------------------------------------
0000:00:02.0                   f000-f03f
0000:00:1f.2                   f060-f07f   f080-f083   f090-f097   f0a0-f0a3   f0b0-f0b7
0000:00:1f.3                   f040-f05f
0000:02:00.0                     e000-e0ff
0000:04:00.0                     d000-d07f
ACPI                           1800-1803   1804-1805   1808-180b   1810-1815   1850-1850   1880-189f
acpi                      9 
ahci                     57      f060-f07f     f080-f083     f090-f097     f0a0-f0a3     f0b0-f0b7
cascade             4       
dma                            0080-008f
dma1                           0000-001f
dma2                           00c0-00df
EC                               0062-0062     0066-0066
eth0                     58 
fpu                            00f0-00ff
i8042                  1 12 
i915                     59 
iTCO_wdt                       1830-1833   1860-187f
iwlwifi                  61 
keyboard                       0060-0060   0064-0064
mei_me                   60 
PCI                          0000-0cf7 0cf8-0cff 0d00-ffff   d000-dfff   e000-efff
pic1                           0020-0021
pic2                           00a0-00a1
pnp                            0240-0259   04d0-04d1   0680-069f   164e-164f   1854-1857   1c00-1cfe   1d00-1dfe   1e00-1efe   1f00-1ffe   ffff-ffff     ffff-ffff       ffff-ffff
PNP0C09:00                     0062-0062   0066-0066
r8169                              e000-e0ff
rtc0                      8    0070-0077
snd_hda_intel         62 63 
timer                     0 
timer0                         0040-0043
timer1                         0050-0053
xhci_hcd                 56
```

Comment: Very good, detailed answer. I like it ! Could use some sample outputs though, but otherwise - no big deal

Comment: @Serg: Added. This answer is huge now!